# preserve inputParser.Results through parse (do not revert to defaults)

Tags: matlab, parsing, key-value, overwrite, optional-parameters

I am using `inputParser` to parse key-value pairs. I would like to run `parse` to get newly incoming key-value pairs, but this overwrites the entire `Results` struct. Here is a demonstration of the behavior vs what I want:

```
parser = inputParser
addParameter(parser, 'param1', nan, @isnumeric);
addParameter(parser, 'param2', nan, @isnumeric);

parse(parser, ['param1', 1234]);
% parser.Results is now {param1:1234, param2:nan}
% all good so far.

parse(parser, ['param1', 567]);
% parser.Results now {param1:567, param2:nan}
% this is also fine.

parse(parser, ['param2', 89]);
% parser.Results is now {param1:nan, param2:89}
% what I want to have : {param1:567, param2:89}
```

In short I do not want `parse` to overwrite previous non-default values with defaults. My first thought was to save the first set of values and then re-insert them into parser.Results, but I found that `You cannot set the read-only property 'Results' of inputParser`.

The only solution I can see is to add the non-default, non-re-given parameters from first set of Results to varargin as key-value pairs, but that sounds like a mess.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

I think the conceptual problem here is treating `parser` as some data storage entity, while its purpose is different - *parsing*.

My idea on how to fix this involves maintaining a separate `struct` (called `model`) that holds the **latest** valid (or default) values of the parameters. Then, after calling `parse()` I send `parser.Results` to a function, `updateParams`, which determines the valid parsed parameters, and then updates `model` accordingly.

```
function model = q38930125
model = struct('param1',NaN,'param2',NaN); % This will hold our list of fields

parser = inputParser;
addParameter(parser, 'param1', NaN, @isnumeric);
addParameter(parser, 'param2', NaN, @isnumeric);

parse(parser, 'param1', 1234);
% parser.Results is now {param1:1234, param2:nan}
% all good so far.
model = updateParams(parser.Results, model);

parse(parser, 'param1', 567);
% parser.Results now {param1:567, param2:nan}
% this is also fine.
model = updateParams(parser.Results, model);

parse(parser, 'param2', 89);
% parser.Results is now {param1:nan, param2:89}
% what I want to have : {param1:567, param2:89}
model = updateParams(parser.Results, model);

end

% Mutator of "model" based on the parse results
function model = updateParams(parserResults, model)
  fields = fieldnames(model);
  for indF = 1:numel(fields)
    tmp = parserResults.(fields{indF});
    if ~isnan(tmp)
      model.(fields{indF}) = tmp;
    end
  end    
end
```

Tested on MATLAB R2016a.

Comment: Thanks for this, it helps a lot. It does however depend on the default values being nan. It's my fault for not addressing this in my example, but ideally i would rather compare with the default values set in the parser. I'll see if I can figure this out and add it to your answer. Thanks again!